# PDF is upload with application/octet-stream

Tags: zend-framework2

I have an Upload in my Application, where the User can upload PDF, PNG, JPG and GIF Files with a maximum file size of 2MB. 
When i upload a PDF with a larger size of 2MB i get the error `File has an incorrect mimetype of 'application/octet-stream'`

Here you can see my Filters an Validators:

```
    'type' => 'Zend\InputFilter\FileInput',
'name' => $name,
'required' => $required,
'filters' => array(
    array(
        'name' => '\Application\Filter\File\RenameUpload',
        'options' => array(
            'target' => 'data/upload',
            'use_upload_name' => true,
            'count_up' => true,
        ),
    ),
),
'validators' => array(
    array('name' => '\Zend\Validator\File\UploadFile'),
    array(
        'name' => '\Zend\Validator\File\Extension',
        'options' => array(
            'extension' => array(
                'pdf',
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png',
                'gif',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Zend\Validator\File\Size',
        'options' => array(
            'max' => '2MB',
            'min' => '1KB',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'name' => '\Zend\Validator\File\MimeType',
        'options' => array(
            'mimeType' => array(
                'application/pdf',
                'image/jpg',
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/gif',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

The `RenameUpload` is an own Filter, which checks if a file with the same name already exists and renames it, by adding a underscore with a Number.

When i add the 'application/octet-stream' MimeType to my Array the Upload works (with the problem, the file will be two times copied to my target directory)

Anyone an idea how i can fix the problem?

Comment: what web server are you using? You can change your web server/apache settings to supply PDFs as application/pdf for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The server (apache) has the right configuration. But your tip brings me to the solution: The jQuery Uploader spilt the file in mulitple parts, so the FileSize validator didn't throw an error and it destroyed the mime-type.